# What are the correct answers to the school teacher's quiz?

Tags: citizens-of-earth

What are the correct answers to be able to recruit the school teacher in Citizens of Earth?

Answer (score 1):

How much does a Bun cost at the Bakery? – $15
How many exterior doors are there in the Capital? – 18
How much health does a Bubble Bee have? – 18
Where does your brother work? – FedUPs
What island nation is south of the Capital? – Panjama
Where does the plumber find items that were washed down the pipes? – Flushmoor

Comment: Would be good to add your source.